# React Native StyleSheet global.js variable style error

Tags: react-native

I'm not sure why, but my app does not like the StyleSheet I created for components. In index.js (top level) I import global var
`import global from './src/global';`
then I use `global.width` which is set to the width of the screen (correctly) in my styles.js file at */src/styles.js*. I then export various styles from the Styles file like the one below called "button". Finally in my button component, I use the array notation for react native styles, giving several widths to the component (assuming the highest index takes precedence), but I just get an error.

**Sample of exported "button" StyleSheet**

```
...
padding: 12,
margin: 10,
//width: global.width/2.0,
alignSelf: "center",
marginTop: "auto",
...
```

**Button Component**

```
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this.props.onPress}
      style={[
        button.regularContainer,
        styles.localButtonStyle,
        this.props.style,
      ]}>
        <Text style={[
          button.regularText,
          styles.localTextStyle,
          this.props.textStyle,
        ]}>
          {this.props.title || 'Button'}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

**Error**

```
Invariant Violation: [33,"RCTView",541,{"color":4278190080,"textAlign":"center","width":"<<NaN>>","backgroundColor":1308622847,"borderWidth":0,"borderColor":4294967295,"marginTop":40}] is not usable as a native method argument
```

These errors go away if I remove the width element from most of the three stylesheets interacting with the component: **button.regularContainer**, **styles.localButtonStyle**, **this.props.style**

**global.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

let global: {
  HermesInternal: null | {}
};

global.width = Dimensions.get('window').width
global.height = Dimensions.get('window').height
global.ios = Platform.OS === 'ios'

export default global;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like it's trying to assign an NaN (Not a number) value to width.

Is global.width/2.0 definitely producing a valid number?

I suggest replacing this division of a variable with an actual number and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: I replaced each global.width with a percentage and the error went away... this doesn't help me understand why global.width doesn't produce a valid number. When I console.log the variable it yields a number. This is frustrating.

Comment: Can you show me how you are initialising the global.width variable in your styles.js ?

Comment: thanks for looking at this. Sorry for the slow response. I updated the question!

Comment: I'm pretty confused as to what is causing the issue, can you try to cast the width property directly to a number before assignment. Like this: `width: Number(global.width/2.0)`

Comment: It really just seems to go in and out of this error––I'll mark this as the solution unless it persists. Also, is the react community small on stack? I thought there would be more movement with this question, despite it being a long post.